# TWIG not applying image style, but computing it

Tags: image, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a problem: my TWIG template is computing the image style, but not applying it.

Code in `news.html.twig`:

```html
<img class="emphasized" src="{{ field_news_emphasized|image_style('emphasized_image') }}" alt="{{ field_news_emphasized.alt }}"/>
```

`field_news_emphasized = public://2019-07/img.jpg`

The image is looking fine, as I wanted to compute it with image style `emphasized_image`, but I still have  a warning `Debug: Could not apply image style emphasized_image. in Drupal\twig_tweak\TwigExtension->imageStyle() (line 843 of modules\contrib\twig_tweak\src\TwigExtension.php).`

Under line 843 in TwigExtension.php is:

```php
    if (!$image_style->supportsUri($path)) {
      trigger_error(sprintf('Could not apply image style %s.', $style));
      return;
    }
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - I was trying to apply image style at two cases, where I didn't have an img loaded (it's an array: exists, NULL, NULL, exists).

`{% if field_news_emphasized != NULL %}`
solved the problem.